# Error 500.19 Internal server error on IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5, http-status-code-500

There are lots of questions about this message error, I tried all the proposed solutions but none of them worked

I have a ASP .NET webapp, I registered the app to IIS and when I visit the page I get this error:

> HTTP Error 500.19 internal server error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid

Error code is: 0x8007000d

[image]

I post my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\ReviewerServices.web.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here what I tried:

- issuing the command "aspnet_regiis.exe -i" after the installation
- assigning full permissions to the entire folder to the user IUSR and IIS_IUSRS
- checking the web.config for syntax errors (none found)
- tried to fudge a little bit the web.config file (looking for non printable ascii, encoding format and such)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is so carefully documented by Microsoft in a step by step way,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis

You forgot to install ASP.NET Core Module for IIS.